# Gauche conformations for 14-electron AH2BH2 systems

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

The hydrazine molecule, and the similar sulfonium/Oxonium ylides, all have a gauche conformation that is more stable than the anti conformation.

Is there any particular reason for this pattern? Orbital Interactions in Chemistry tries to use overlap between the 2 “lone pair” orbitals on the carbons as a justification (since it’s a 2 center 4-electron interaction).

Comment: They don't try to use that, they do it, and it does explain the structure. I think the ordinary organic chemist (and probably most of the other chemists, too) would call that negative hyperconjugation.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1749518 https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00762a030